# I have a 'interop exception' with a consumer contract test under .NET

Tags: .net, pact

I had code working with [Pact](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby) v3. I have upgraded to Pact v4, and have followed the instructions in the upgrade guide.

When I run a Pact consumer test, I get the following error:

```
 Message:  PactNet.Exceptions.PactFailureException : Unable to perform
 the given action. The interop call indicated failure

   Stack Trace:  InteropActionExtensions.CheckInteropSuccess(Boolean
 success) HttpInteractionDriver.WithRequest(String method, String path)
 RequestBuilder.WithRequest(String method, String path)
 RequestBuilder.WithRequest(HttpMethod method, String path)
 IRequestBuilderV2.WithRequest(HttpMethod method, String path)
 CasClientPact.EnsureCasClientHandlesAddItemEndpointWhenAlreadyIn() line 63
```

#### Versions

- Operating system: [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11)
- .NET:  6.0
- [Pact Net](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net):  4.5.0
- [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit): 3.13.3
- NUnit3TestAdapter: 4.5.0
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk: 17.7.2

#### Demo project

- Git: *[Capstone project](https://github.com/phil-rice/CandidateSourcing)*
- Tag: PactNotWorking
- Test: project casClient, file: cas.pact.consumer.test.cs

#### Sample code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using PactNet.Infrastructure.Outputters;
using PactNet;
      public CasClientPact()
      {
          var config = new PactConfig
          {
              PactDir = @"..\..\..\..\artifacts\pacts"
          };
          IPactV2 pact = Pact.V2("CasClient", "Cas", config);
          this.pact = pact.WithHttpInteractions(9222);
      }

       [Test]
       async public Task EnsureCasClientHandlesAddItemEndpointWhenAlreadyIn()
       {
           pact
          .UponReceiving("A request to add item that is already stored")
          .WithRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/cas/someNs")
          .WithBody("alreadyin", "application/octet-stream")
          .WillRespond()
          .WithStatus(200)
          .WithBody("/cas/someNs/content/-AFBB8Hv7uIEEmV1Srn0Y-OkfnMplM-FX8TEh4-SucM", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

           await pact.VerifyAsync(async ctx =>
           {
               byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("alreadyin");
               var result = await Client.AddItemAsync("someNs", bytes, "application/octet-stream");
               Assert.AreEqual("/cas/someNs/content/-AFBB8Hv7uIEEmV1Srn0Y-OkfnMplM-FX8TEh4-SucM", result);
           });
       }
```

Comment: It might be related to this open issue when the framework is NUnit - https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/issues/471

Comment: Thank you Pawel. I will update the issue with a sample repo

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when the `.Given` call had Turkish characters (`ş` or `ı` to be specific) in it. Your code has no `.Given` call; I'd suggest that you add one and see what happens.

Comment: I disagree: I'm telling how I resolved the same problem on my side and proposing a solution.

Comment: Then please rephrase it umambiguously "if you have … then you should do …"

Comment: With due respect, I cannot see why my answer should be a comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @Adriaan I disagree - it appears to be a good-faith attempt to answer the question. I don't have the domain expertise to know whether it's a *correct* answer or not, but that's what voting is for.

Comment: It might have been [U+0131](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I) ([LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=300)). UTF-8 sequence: 304 261 (octal). 0xC4 0xB1 (hexadecimal). It can be searched for (and replaced) using the regular expression `\x{0131}` in any modern text editor (there is a different notation, "\u0131" in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and some others).